# Invalid registration python FCM

Tags: python, firebase, registration, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification from a python script to an android application using Firebase.  Here is my code:

```
from pyfcm import FCMNotification
apikey ="apikey"
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=apikey)

registration_id = "regid"
message_title = "Uber update"
message_body = "Hope you're having fun this weekend, don't forget to check today's news"
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
print (result)
```

The error I am getting when I run it is invalid registration.  Could this be because I have not sent have the registration token to the server.  I have tried this, but I am not sure if it has been sent. Is there a way I could check it?

I can update the Firebase database and receive information from it, but I can't figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. [InvalidRegistration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) error means that the registration token you're sending the message to is invalid. Double check the value of the registration token and make sure it is correct. If you successfully sent a message to the FCM server, you should receive a 200 OK response along with a `message_id`. Cheers! :)

Comment: How would I check the registration token.

Comment: The value of it I mean

Comment: from where do you get the registration token ?